# Google webmaster does not index full sitemap?

Tags: google-search-console

My URL is: www.etypeservices.synology.me/etypes/

on the above URL i have several folders and sub folders which contains PDF files, i have tried since more that two weeks but google webmaster tools doesn't index complete sitemap, sitemap contains more than 3000 url but in indexing report it only shows approx 800 urls are index, also it is not showing any kind of errors in sitemap aur urls, then i didn't understand what is the reason why google webmaster not index my complete sitemap here is, one more thing these files are on nas drive and nas drive is hosted with above url, and here is the url of sitemap http://www.etypeservices.synology.me/etypes/sitemap.xml